How do we use as if with past tense?
Can anyone explain the difference between this sentences?
1.

“The drops of water rose all around her as if it rained.”


(Cambridge Dictionary says you can use a non-finite clause with as if.)


“The drops of water rose all around her as if to rain.”

“She moved her lips as if to smile.”






“The drops of water rose all around her as if raining.”

“She moved her lips as if smiling.”



#1 is not idiomatic. #2 would be peculiar, but there's nothing odd about, say, She moved her arm back as if to slap him, so the syntactic construction itself is fine. So is She moved her arms as if waving, but actually she was drowning.


The drops of water rose all around her as if it rained (it's not true that it rains.)

She moved her lips as if to smile. (She moved her lips like she was going to smile.)

She moved her lips as if smiling. (She moved her lips in a way that resembled a smile.)


I'm unable to provide a source to support this so don't trust this answer unless a few people confirm it.
